# How to create an azure custom role

Tags: azure

I am looking for someone who's created a custom role in Azure for Network Administrators, that would be willing to share their handiwork. Why re-invent the wheel?

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom role like this:

```
$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition "Virtual Machine Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "Virtual Machine Operator"
$role.Description = "Can monitor and restart virtual machines."
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Storage/*/read")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Network/*/read")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Compute/*/read")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Authorization/*/read")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Support/*")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/c276fc76-9cd4-44c9-99a7- 4fd71546436e")
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/e91d47c4-76f3-4271-a796-21b4ecfe3624")
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

It starts with an already existing role and then adds read permissions to compute, storage, etc.

Have a look at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell#create-role-with-psroledefinitionobject) for more information on how to create and configure custom roles.